# How can I delete specific row instead of always the first row (Modal)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a CRM app and try to delete a specific client when the confirmation button is clicked in the pop-up modal, but it always deletes the first client. I know that it happened due to the ambiguous class name, and the problem may be solved by adding a unique id for each client? I have been searching around for this type of problem but still not sure how to solve it. Since I generated every client by a for loop and I might need to dynamically create a unique id for each client and call the specific id in javascript and modify the corresponding CSS? I feel that this way might be over-complicated. Are there any other methods to achieve my goal? Thanks.

```js
function clientmodal() {
  document.querySelector('.modal-bg').style.visibility = 'visible';
  document.querySelector('.modal-bg').style.opacity = '1';
}

function clientcancel() {
  document.querySelector('.modal-bg').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.querySelector('.modal-bg').style.opacity = '0';
}
```

```css
.modal-bg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s;
}

.delete-modal {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 13%;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!-- client table -->

{% for user in clients %}

<tr class="mt-3">
  <td class="pt-3">{{ user.level }}</td>
  <td class="pt-3"><a href="{% url 'clients' user.id %}">{{ user.first_name }}</a></td>
  <td class="pt-3">{{ user.last_name }}</td>
  <td class="pt-3">{{ user.country }}</td>
  <td class="pt-3">{{ user.contact }}</td>
  <td class="pt-3">{{ user.contact_number }}</td>
  <!-- <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Client Info</a>  -->
  <td><a href="{% url 'update' user.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Update</a>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="clientmodal()">Delete</a></td>
</tr>


<!-- client modals -->

<div class="modal-bg">
  <div class="delete-modal">
    <div class="modal-title">
      <h3>Are you sure you want to delete this client?</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-secondary cancel" onclick="clientcancel()">Cancel</a>
      <a href="{% url 'delete' user.id %}" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. This is not a Django related question. Please edit the snippet and add 3 RENDERED rows in plain HTML

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector()` search for one item, and when it find one of them it remove it.

In your case, there is multiple line with search param, so it will find more than one item, but it will always choose the first.

So, you have to identify line with an ID. For example you can do:

```html
<tr class="mt-3" id="line-user-{{ user.id }}">
    <td class="pt-3">{{ user.level }}</td>
    <td class="pt-3">all others TDs</td>
</tr>
```

```js
var item = document.querySelector('#line-input-' + userId);
item.style.visibility = 'hidden';
item.style.opacity = '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things

Please study the code below

1. I moved the modal outside the loop and send the userid to it when the row is accessed
2. I moved the visibility from the CSS to a .hide class
3. I add and remove this class
4. I use delegation from the table body that also contains the ID of the user in a data attribute

I recommend you do not have hrefs that delete stuff. One visit from google bot will wipe your user database. Instead use ajax where I commented

```js
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal-bg');
const modalLink = modal.querySelector(".confirm");
let currentRow;
document.getElementById("tb").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const parent = e.target.closest("tr");
  const id = parent.dataset.userid;
  currentRow = parent;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("delete")) {
    e.preventDefault()
    modal.classList.remove("hide");
    modalLink.href = `{{ url }}?id=${id}`;
  }
});
modal.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // e.preventDefault(); // here you REALLY should ajax
  if (currentRow && e.target.classList.contains("confirm")) currentRow.remove()
  modal.classList.add("hide");
})
```

```css
.modal-bg {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s;
}

.delete-modal {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 13%;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr class="mt-3" data-userid="{% user.id %}">
      <td class="pt-3">1</td>
      <td class="pt-3"><a href="">A1</a></td>
      <td class="pt-3">B1</td>
      <td class="pt-3">C1</td>
      <td class="pt-3">D1</td>
      <td class="pt-3">E1</td>
      <td><a href="{% url 'update' user.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Update</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-danger delete">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="mt-3" data-userid="{% user.id %}">
      <td class="pt-3">2</td>
      <td class="pt-3"><a href="">A2</a></td>
      <td class="pt-3">B2</td>
      <td class="pt-3">C2</td>
      <td class="pt-3">D2</td>
      <td class="pt-3">E2</td>
      <td><a href="{% url 'update' user.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Update</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-danger delete">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<!-- client modals -->

<div class="modal-bg hide">
  <div class="delete-modal">
    <div class="modal-title">
      <h3>Are you sure you want to delete this client?</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-secondary cancel">Cancel</a>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-danger confirm">Yes</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```